# Form submission failed:404 error

Tags: php

When trying to submit the form am getting the following error:

You don't have permission to access /refstyle/displayfile.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

php code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<button type="submit">Save</button>
<textarea name="style" id="refstyle"><?php echo file_get_contents("example.bib");?></textarea>
</form>
```

If I removed form, everything works fine.Searched a lot but none of them worked.

Comment: This form can´t go to 404, when its send on the same page.

Comment: It can if javascript alters the action after loading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had that problem, I had to run:

```
chmod 755 [filename]
```

from the shell, and that fixed the issue.